# Python boolean expression

Tags: python, boolean-expression, simpy

I want to save booleanexpressions into file in most memory effective way. There are some relations between the booleans that do not need to be saved into file, but are assumed.
One of my ideas is to save it in DNF, that skips the lines, that are false because of the relation, that do not have to be saved. Since often there are very many booleans in expression, but the expression is simple, it should somehow but the rows, that are only conjucated together.

Are there any standard ways to so that? Is there any module for this?
I am using python, but I do not mean python-syntaks boolean-expression like:

```
A and B and C or (D==A)
```

I am currently using sympy, but in simplification of long expressions it is very slow and it does not offer method to save booleanexpression in most memory effective way.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this  python module [PyEDA](http://pyeda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boolalg.html)

*Boolean Algebra is a cornerstone of electronic design automation, and fundamental to several other areas of computer science and engineering. PyEDA has an extensive library for the creation and analysis of Boolean functions.*

Comment: PyEDA can save expressions in canonical normal form, but I also want to save expressions where some relations between booleans are assumed(and do not need to be saved.) For example if is assumed, that (a→b)&(c→b) then saving f(a,b,c,d) takes only 10 bits, not 16 bits.

Comment: Maybe I will. I asked this question to find out if such module is already made.